# is there a way to make a lostfocus event in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

what I want to do is that if I type "c" on the textbox and if I tab the textbox, it should display "cash". I think it's possible but I don't know how. can anyone help me?

Comment: You'd want to do this in JavaScript. I suggest looking at this: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: I see it sir.. but what I meant there is that when I type "c"/"C" on a textbox1 and when I go to textbox2 the textbox1 should have "Cash" input on it.

Comment: That sounds like a bad user-interface design to me. Please explain what you want to accomplish and why.

Comment: it's actually a simple pos that I am working on! I actually got it. using java script and onblur event..

Answer (score 0):

this is what I do.

first I add this event onblur to formload

```
     txtsoldto.Attributes.Add("onblur", "blurMe()")
```

then I use JavaScript to make a lostfocus like event.

```
function blurMe() {
    var textboxObj = document.getElementById("txtsoldto");
    var textbox1Val = textboxObj.value;
    if (textbox1Val == "A" || textbox1Val == "a") {
        textboxObj.value = "Account";
        document.getElementById("txtbarcode").focus();
    }
```